# Erasing duplicates with NA values

Tags: r, duplicates, slice

I have a data frame like this:

```
names <- c('Mike','Mike','Mike','John','John','John','David','David','David','David')
dates <- c('04-26','04-26','04-27','04-28','04-27','04-26','04-01','04-02','04-02','04-03')
values <- c(NA,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,NA,NA)
test <- data.frame(names,dates,values)
```

Which is:

```
  names dates values
1  Mike 04-26     NA
2  Mike 04-26      1
3  Mike 04-27      2
4  John 04-28      4
5  John 04-27      5
6  John 04-26      6
7 David 04-01      1
8 David 04-02      2
9 David 04-02     NA
10 David 04-03    NA
```

I'd like to get rid of duplicates with `NA` values. So, in this case, I have a valid observation from Mike on 04-26 and also have a valid observation from David on 04-02, so rows 1 and 9 should be erased and I will end up with:

```
      names dates values
1  Mike 04-26      1
2  Mike 04-27      2
3  John 04-28      4
4  John 04-27      5
5  John 04-26      6
6 David 04-01      1
7 David 04-02      2
8 David 04-03      NA
```

I tried to use `duplicated` function, something like this:

```
test[!duplicated(test[,c('names','dates')]),]
```

But that does not work since some `NA` values come before the valid value. Do you have any suggestions without trying things like `merge` or making another data frame?

Update: I'd like to keep rows with `NA` that are not duplicates.

Comment: What if there is `NA` but no duplication?

Comment: I'd like to keep `NA` values with no duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt in `data.table`:

```
# set up
libary(data.table)
setDT(test)

# construct condition
test[, dupes := max(duplicated(.SD)), .SDcols=c("names", "dates"), by=c("names", "dates")]

# print out result
test[dupes == 0 | !is.na(values),]
```

Here is a similar method using base R, except that the dupes variable is kept separately from the data.frame:

```
dupes <- duplicated(test[c("names", "dates")])
# this generates warnings, but works nonetheless
dupes <- ave(dupes, test$names, test$dates, FUN=max)
# print out result
test[dupes == 0 | !is.na(test$values),]
```

If there are duplicated rows where the values variable is NA, and these duplicates add nothing to the data, then you can drop them prior to running the code above:

```
testNoNADupes <- test[!(duplicated(test) & is.na(test$values)),]
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for. Though, for a large data set that I have (2 million rows), it is kind of slow.

Comment: @Imo What if there was another row `David 04-03      NA` and we wanted to keep `David 04-03      NA`? Because noth these rows are NA and dupes, `David 04-03      NA` will be erased. However, we want to keep it.

Comment: @bikhaab See the last line of code for one method of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 3):

What about this way?

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% group_by(names, dates) %>% filter((n()>=2 & !is.na(values)) | n()==1)
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: names, dates [8]

   names  dates values
  (fctr) (fctr)  (dbl)
1   Mike  04-26      1
2   Mike  04-27      2
3   John  04-28      4
4   John  04-27      5
5   John  04-26      6
6  David  04-01      1
7  David  04-02      2
8  David  04-03     NA
```

Comment: Or, inspired by the [tag:slice] tag: `test %>% arrange(values) %>% group_by(names, dates) %>% slice(1L)` since when you `arrange`, the `NA`s go to the end.

Comment: This works great. It would be great if the column names would not change.

Comment: @bikhaab They actually don't change, they are just printed that way but the column names remain the same

Answer (score 0):

This should work based on your sample.

```
test <- test[order(test$values),]
test <- test[!(duplicated(test$names) & duplicated(test$dates) & is.na(test$values)),]
```

Comment: I don't like to change the order of the rows. Also, this was just an example and the solution wouldn't work for a general case.

Comment: `test <- test[sample(nrow(test), 2000000, replace=T)`. This still work for me.. If it doesn't for you consider to modify your question.